# Does the ternary operator work in constant definition?

Tags: objective-c, syntax, ternary

Why do I get a compiler error when using a ternary operator in the assignment of a CGSize const like this?

```
CGSize const ksizeSmall = SOME_BOOLEAN_VARIABLE ? {187, 187} : {206, 206};
```

it does work like this...

```
CGSize const ksizeSmall = {187, 187};
```

however, I want to add a boolean expression to evaluate whether I should use one size vs. the other size. I don't want to use if / else because I have a long list of CGSize to set specifically for different purposes.

Comment: Is `SOME_BOOLEAN_VARIABLE` a compile-time constant?

Comment: What does the compiler error say?

Comment: SOME_BOOLEAN_VARIABLE is a macro that evaluates to "bool"

Comment: @EwanMellor The compiler says "Expected ':'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`{187, 187}` and `{206, 206}` *aggregates* are valid as an initialization expressions, but not as a general-purpose expressions<sup>*</sup>. That is why a ternary operator does not allow it.

If you are making an initializer for a local constant, you could use `CGSizeMake`:

```
CGSize const ksizeSmall = SOME_BOOLEAN_VARIABLE ? CGSizeMake(187, 187) : CGSizeMake(206, 206);
```

If `SOME_BOOLEAN_VARIABLE` is a compile-time constant expression, you could use conditional compilation instead:

```
#if SOME_BOOLEAN_VARIABLE
CGSize const ksizeSmall = {187, 187};
#else
CGSize const ksizeSmall = {206, 206};
#endif
```

<sup>*</sup> gcc compiler has a C language extension that offers a special syntax for doing this. It was available in Objective-C as well. However, this extension is not part of the language.

Comment: This is exactly the info I needed. The compiler wasn't really providing any real info as to what was not allowed. I've accepted your answer. Thanks for your time.